# Laravel loop position

Tags: php, laravel

How can I have my posts position such as image below in laravel 5.4

[image]

this is my loop currently:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <div class="card">
        <header class="card-header">
            <p class="card-header-title">
                <a href="{{ route('frontshow', $post->slug ) }}">{{ $post->title }}</a>
            </p>
            <a class="card-header-icon">
                <span class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </span>
            </a>
        </header>
        <div class="card-content">
            <div class="content">
                {{  str_limit($post->body, 100) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I want my posts be like `left-right` `right-left` and continues.

Comment: You will use css for that.

Comment: @aldrin27 I don't think so! css comes from bootstrap itself's but in this case i think i need use collective but not sure how! that's why i asked here.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do the trick using CSS3: below is an example

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
}

.card + .card {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.card .card-header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  background: grey;
}

.card:nth-child(even) .card-header {
 order: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <header class="card-header">
      <p class="card-header-title">
        <a href="{{ route('frontshow', $post->slug ) }}">Post Title 1</a>
      </p>
      <a class="card-header-icon">
        <span class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </span>
      </a>
    </header>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="content">
        Content goes here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <header class="card-header">
      <p class="card-header-title">
        <a href="{{ route('frontshow', $post->slug ) }}">Post Title 2</a>
      </p>
      <a class="card-header-icon">
        <span class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </span>
      </a>
    </header>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="content">
        Content goes here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <header class="card-header">
      <p class="card-header-title">
        <a href="{{ route('frontshow', $post->slug ) }}">Post Title 3</a>
      </p>
      <a class="card-header-icon">
        <span class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </span>
      </a>
    </header>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="content">
        Content goes here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through every item with a counter variable like `$i` and then check the result of

```
$className = $i % 2 === 0 ? 'left-right' : 'right-left';
```

That will set the proper class.

Read more about Modulo operator from [**PHP Manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

On a blade side it can look like:

```
@foreach ($items as $i => $item)
    @if ($i % 2 == 0)
    // left-right
    @else
    // right-left
    @endif 
@endforeach
```

Comment: you know have a $loop var within blade loops, can be usefull :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a condition like this inside your loop :

```
@if $loop->index %2 == 0
 // add a css class for even element like 'left-right'
@else
 // add the other css class 'right-left'
@endif
```

Comment: i tried this but it shows the same  `@foreach ($posts as $post)
    @if ($post->index %2 == 0)
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">{{ $post->name }}</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">{{ $post->link }}</div>
    </div>
    @else
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">{{ $post->name }}</div>
      <div class="col-md-8">{{ $post->link }}</div>
    </div>
    @endif
    @endforeach`

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/thDUB it supposed to be second one link in left side and name in right

Comment: hey, it's $loop->index not $post, it's a blade loop var